# "apt-get remove python" removed a ton of other stuff, RPi messed up

Tags: ssh, boot-issues, apt, python-2.x

So I was trying to install the Python library `lzma`, and somehow I got to the point of removing python2.x, and I don't know why I did that. I'm tired, that probably why. I think I learned my lesson.

Anyways the damage is done. I ran `apt-get remove python`. It then preceded to remove a crap ton of other stuff stuff related to python, and also a bunch of programs I had installed. I do not know why this happened. I rebooted, and now I don't know what exactly happened to it, so I'm just going to take a picture.
[image]

It is just stuck on that. I tried pressing Ctrl-Alt-T for a terminal, nope, didn't do anything.

Luckily I have an SSH server that starts on boot, and I successfully logged into that, and I have root.

I have a bunch of files on there that I cannot lose. Im also an idiot for not taking backups.

How can I restore my Pi back to what it was like before?

I have tried:

- `apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `apt full-upgrade`
- `apt-get install python`

EDIT: I do have NOOBS installed on the sdcard, so I can hold shift while booting to get into NOOBS

Also the Pi in question is an RPi3, and it was on Raspbian Pixel

Update: I logged into SSH and ran `sudo raspi-config` and made it so the Pi just boots to CLI.

Comment: You would be better off using SSH (SCP https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh) to retrieve your unbacked up files and starting fresh. Take this as a learning opportunity and implement a proper backup procedure for the new system.

Comment: @Steve Robillard dang. ok. that kinda sucks to because they are scattered all over the system

Comment: Just learn the lesson as much as it may hurt or a PITA, it is far worse the second time when you know better.

Comment: @SteveRobillard So right now All I got on me is my phone (rooted Nexus6p) a few flash drives and my Pi setup. The flash drives are 4gb, 16gb & 32gb. You mind helping me figure out how to fix this? Pi does have ADB installed

Comment: @SteveRobillard and an OTG cable

Comment: @SteveRobillard sorry I also have a microSD=>usb adapter

Comment: This will be much easier with another computer (especially creating the new SD card image).  You can search for an scp app for your phone and backup your files.  Likewise, a web search or even a search on this site should show you how to burn a new SD card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing Python is not a minor issue the resulting problems can lurk unseen for a long period of time only to bite you later (e.g. a missing library that was uninstalled and not reinstalled breaks a seldom used feature). As a result, I think you would be better off backing up the important files you mentioned using SCP and starting over, by reimaging your SD card.

To copy files from your Pi to your PC I would suggest [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). If you are using a MAC or another Linux machine SCP is built in. This [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/) should get you going.

Some additional things to consider:

- Do you still need noobs or should you just switch to Raspbian directly?
- How you manage the files and scripts you mention are scattered all over the file system.
- Implementing a backup solution.

Comment: Right now im just `adb push`ing everything important

Comment: Whatever works to backup your important files before reimaging the SD card.